# Unable to Install Darkest Dark Theme MyEclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, myeclipse, eclipse-marketplace

(MyEclipse Version: 2017 CI 4)
I had the "Darkest Dark Theme" (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme) installed in my eclipse, and tried updating but it failed. I uninstalled the theme from the marketplace, to try installing a fresh copy, but Now I'm getting this:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Darkest Dark Theme 1.8.0.201705081336 

(com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.feature.feature.group 1.8.0.201705081336)
  Software currently installed: MyEclipse 2017 CI 15.0.0.c0000007t201704070416 

(package.8219-Cse-3417.windows.x86_64 15.0.0.c0000007t201704070416)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Flat Scrollbar - Windows and Linux 1.7.0.201701310235 

(com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.scrollbar.win 1.7.0.201701310235)
    Flat Scrollbar - Windows and Linux 1.8.0.201705050950 

(com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.scrollbar.win 1.8.0.201705050950)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Darkest Dark Theme 1.8.0.201705081336 

(com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.feature.feature.group 1.8.0.201705081336)
    To: com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.scrollbar.win [1.8.0.201705050950]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: MyEclipse 2017 CI 15.0.0.c0000007t201704070416 (package.8219-Cse-3417.windows.x86_64 15.0.0.c0000007t201704070416)
    To: com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.scrollbar.win [1.7.0.201701310235]
```

Any ideas how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your version of MyEclipse has version 1.7 or the com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.scrollbar.win plugin installed and says that is the only version that is acceptable. The theme wants version 1.8 - so it looks like this can't be installed in this version of MyEclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyEclipse 2017 CI 4 already contains the Darkest Dark (DD) theme. Trying to install a later version of DD from the Marketplace will probably bring up conflicts. If you're looking for a later version of DD, then MyEclipse 2017 CI 5 will contain it, so I suggest you check for updates in MyEclipse, to get it installed (though you would get a notification, eventually, anyway).

Comment: I was looking for a later version (to fix the MyLyn task list for the DD theme). MyEclipse 2017 CI 5 fixed my issues (although I am a little confused as to why they have conflicting versions of the scrollbar). Thanks!